# Create a Tree Stump Matlab

Tags: matlab, tree, decision-tree

Any idea on how to create a decision tree stump for use with boosting in Matlab? I mean is there some parameter I can send to classregtree to make sure i end up with only 1 level? I tried pruning and it doesn't always give a stump (single cut). Sometimes I was only able to get 2 cuts (unbalanced tree).

I'm aware of the ClassificationTree.template and the fitensemble functions but I want to write my own boosting algorithm to use it with LDA or other classifiers which are not provided by fitensemble.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you can just set the `minparent` parameter equal to your number of observations. Using the iris example data:

```
>> load fisheriris;
>> t = classregtree(meas,species,...
                 'names',{'SL' 'SW' 'PL' 'PW'}, 'minparent', 150)

t = 

Decision tree for classification
1  if PL<2.45 then node 2 elseif PL>=2.45 then node 3 else setosa
2  class = setosa
3  class = versicolor
```

Not sure, but it may be quicker to eventually code it manually - especially if you're incorporating other custom code anyway. Good luck!

Comment: Actually sometimes it just doesn't cut at all i.e. tree is made of only the root node :S

Comment: Hmm...is there a small example you could post? If not, trying working through the other options at http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/classregtree.html . For one example, if the risks are equal and `mergeleaves` is left at its default ("on"), then I don't think there will be a cut.

Answer (score 0):

If `t1` is your tree, as returned by `classregtree`, I think you can create a decision stump `t2` with the command

```
t2 = prune(t1, 'level', max(prunelist(t1)-1));
```

Does that do what you need?

Comment: Well 1- Its not efficient and 2- it happens that if the tree is unbalanced, the prune might favor 1 side to the other so I end up with a tree with one split in the left branch but none in the right branch and if I increase 1 more level, I end up with the root node. Not sure if turning merge leaves off would solve that though. Thanks for the suggestion though :-)